# Struts tiles - a simple putList causes parse error

Tags: java, parsing, struts, tiles

It has been a while since I did something in tiles. I am trying to build a simple website with some "bread crumb" feature. I would use static bread crumbs as my page navigation is pretty limited. Here is my `tiles-defs.xml` file:

```
<tiles-definitions> 
   <definition name=".template" path="/pages/template.jsp">
        <put name="title" value="Template"/>
        <put name="header" value="/pages/common_header.jsp"/>
        <putList name="breadcrumb"/>
        <put name="body" value="/pages/sample.jsp"/>
        <put name="footer" value="/pages/common_footer.jsp"/>
    </definition>

    <!-- staring page for the application -->
    <definition name=".start.page" extends=".template">
        <put name="title" value="Server details"/>
        <putList name="breadcrumb">
            <item value="Home" link="#"/>
        </putList>
        <put name="body" value="pages/home.jsp" type="page"/>
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Just by introducing `<putList name="breadcrumb">` the tiles-defs refuses to parse: I keep getting the following error:

```
SEVERE: Parse Error at line 45 column 18: The content of element type "definition" must match "(icon?,display-name?,description?,put*,putList*)".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "definition" must match "(icon?,display-name?,description?,put*,putList*)".
```

This is really a head-scratcher. Any idea what is going wrong?
Using Struts 1.3.8 JARs

Comment: I've edited the answer. Sorry there was an error with the format and it couldn't be read properly.

Answer (score 4):

It is complaining about the order of the elements. You have put first the "put" elements and after all of them the "putList" ones.
So the code would be something like this:

```
<tiles-definitions> 
    <definition name=".template" path="/pages/template.jsp">
        <put name="title" value="Template"/>
        <put name="header" value="/pages/common_header.jsp"/>
        <put name="body" value="/pages/sample.jsp"/>
        <put name="footer" value="/pages/common_footer.jsp"/>
        <putList name="breadcrumb"/>
    </definition>

    <!-- staring page for the application -->
    <definition name=".start.page" extends=".template">
        <put name="title" value="Server details"/>
        <put name="body" value="pages/home.jsp" type="page"/>
        <putList name="breadcrumb">
            <item value="Home" link="#"/>
        </putList>
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Comment: I did not understand your answer - can you please elaborate?

Comment: The "putList" tag has to be written after all the "put" tags.